How to change the font within an EPS file generated in Matlab?
I use Matlab to generate .eps files, and I use the Latex interpreter to typeset axes and legends. Unfortunately, the Matlab does not have any options to select the font of the Latex interpreter.
What I want is as follows:

To be able to make sure font sizes of the numbers/texts in the plots are the same as those in the main body
To be able to select the font in the figure: either the main body font or the math mode font of the document itself.

I saw psfrag, but it is utterly confusing to me at this point.

Do either of these help answer the question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8478653/how-to-edit-eps-file-to-change-fonts , https://www.template.net/adobe/how-to-change-font-in-adobe-illustrator-for-eps-file,

I would produce a .svg file instead, open it in inkscape and save as pdf_tex file. This will split the graphic into to parts: a .pdf file with the lines etc. and a .pdf_tex file which contains the tex code for all the text. This way all axis labels etc. will match the surrounding text font.
